# Woocommerce - Add Product with a Note (CustomPage)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I created a custom page with products to select from a dropdown.

Then I add the selected product to cart with:

```php
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cartItemData);
```

I want to pass:

```
$cartItemData= array ('Bundle' => 'BuildYourOwnProduct');
```

within the $cartItemData and display it within the cart like so

[image: Display in Cart]

And I also need to make sure this gets passed to the order notes within the order.
Anyone has any suggestions on how to approach this?